# How to move div without affecting my container div?

Tags: css, html

So I have a nav menu that I have floating on the left. I would like to move it more to the right without affecting the container. When I use padding or margin it moves it, when I try

```
 position: absolute;
```

It just moves the container to the left and minimizes it.

[RESOLVED]

All help is appreciated, still pretty new to html/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Menu

```
position: absolute; 
margin-left: 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
position: relative;
left: 100px; /* or however far you want to move it to the right */
```

Comment: Relative position puts the menu back in the flow of the document. If he re-does his container positioning to accommodate for that then your answer would work.

Comment: No, he said it's floating to the left, and he wants to bump it across a bit without affecting the container.  That's exactly what `position: relative` does -- it moves the element without affecting any of the rest of the flow of the document.

Comment: Relative puts the element back in the document flow. This link explains css positioning. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Yes and it's already IN the document flow.  He said he **tried** `position:absolute`, not that he was using it.

Comment: Here is a link to the page open in chrome or firebug and try them out. http://craftedbyfrank.com/test/

Comment: Mate, one of us didn't understand the question.  I've been doing this for 10+ years, I know how CSS positioning works.

Comment: @leftclickben I tried position:absolute on the container not the menu.

Comment: I thank you both for your contributions, no need to fight though.